# POSTING json data syntax issues

Tags: react-native

I am doing a task that requires me to POST a list item to an API via a mobile app using react native. 
I have text inputs that takes the users inputs and then when they click the button it will post those inputs to the API server. The issue is, three of the inputs(id, unit_price and quantity) are numbers and when I POST lets say an id of 5, it appears as : "5" which stops it from being fully POSTED since it's not in JSON format.

The question is how do I make sure the (" ") aren't around by numbers when POSTING to the API.

[Results in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI72k.png)

Text inputs and save button:

````
 <TextInput style = {styles.ListText}
    underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
    placeholder = "Enter ID here"
    autoCapitalize = "none"
    onChangeText={val => this.setState({ id: text })}
    />

  <TextInput style = {styles.ListText}
    underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
    placeholder = "Enter item_name here"
    autoCapitalize = "none"
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ item_name: text }) }
    />

<TextInput style = {styles.ListText}
    underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
    placeholder = "Enter description here"
    autoCapitalize = "none"
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ description: text })}
    />

<TextInput style = {styles.ListText}
    underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
    placeholder = "Enter unit_price here"
    autoCapitalize = "none"
    onChangeText={val => this.setState({ unit_price: text })}
    />
<TextInput style = {styles.ListText}
    underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
    placeholder = "Enter quantity here"
    autoCapitalize = "none"
    onChangeText={val => this.setState({ quantity: text })}
    />

    <TouchableOpacity
       style = {styles.Button}
       onPress =
       {
         () => this.addItem()
       }>
       <Text style = {styles.ButtonText}> ADD </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>```




The POST function:

addItem(){
 return fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3333/list",
 {
method: 'POST',
headers:{
  //'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  id: this.state.id,
  item_name: this.state.item_name,
  description: this.state.description,
  unit_price: this.state.unit_price,
  quantity: this.state.quantity
})
 })
 .then((response) => {
 Alert.alert("Item Added!");

 })
 .catch((error) => {
 console.error(error);
 });
}
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using parseInt()

```
...
body: JSON.stringify({
  id: this.state.id,
  item_name: this.state.item_name,
  description: this.state.description,
  unit_price: parseInt(this.state.unit_price),
  quantity: parseInt(this.state.quantity)
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `parseInt(String)` ([docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)) will parse a string to an integer. Like I see from the [documents of Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will JSON.stringify(Array) post the variable as integer in the JSON response.

**Example**

```
JSON.stringify({
  id: parseInt(this.state.id),
  item_name: this.state.item_name,
  description: this.state.description,
  unit_price: parseInt(this.state.unit_price),
  quantity: parseInt(this.state.quantity)
});
```